# HTML Component for two level list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

Before writing a new directive to get what I want, just wondering if is there any component (maybe Angular-UI or Bootstrap) that allows browsing a list, and by selecting an element, showing a second list related to the selected element on the first one.
A tree is not the proper answer to this, for usability and L&F reasons.

I was thinking in a breadcrumbs + a single list holder: first level elements are shown by default in the list holder, and when an element is selected, breadcrumb is updated with the element name/title, and list holder contents is replaced by the second level related elements.

Default / Home state:

```
----
\
----
element-1 >
element-2 >
...
element-n >
----
```

After selection of element-2 by clicking on ">":

```
----
element-2 \
----
element2.1
element2.2
...
element2.m
----
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use nested list elements.

If you place a second `<ul>` inside a `<li>` you can hide it by default. And either use CSS to display the hidden items on hover. OR, use a combination of CSS and Javascript/jQuery to give the parent `<li>` a class of something like `active` when clicked, which in turn displays the hidden items.

Example HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Item
    <ul>
      <li>SubItem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example CSS:

```
ul ul { display:none }
ul li:hover ul { display:block }
```

OR

Example CSS:

```
ul ul { display:none }
ul li.active ul { display:block }
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zho99zwa/

Comment: I'm thinking in something more like a browser, with click interaction to access the next level of elements

Comment: You can change the type of item being nested. Lists are just a really simple example. Aaaand, if you take the approach using Javascript / jQuery then you can change it to onClick events in oppose to hover.